# Include external JS file from base page

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

For my pages which implement feature X I have them implement a base class (which itself implements the original base). 

This feature X base class has some web methods, and I'd like the javascript that's required in using those web methods to be included in the concrete page's  in the form:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" src="FeatureX.js"></SCRIPT>
```

I thought it would be as simple as adding the attribute to base.Header in the base class - but it's null.
 From googling and searching SO it seems I should be making a new master page, as this is related to presentation. However that seems like overkill for one include statement. Is there some way I can add this straight from the base class? 
Thanks.

Comment: seems correct ! is the JS file placed in the same folder as the aspx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply add

```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("coursel", ResolveUrl("FeatureX.js"));
```

Comment: Make sure to preface that code with  if if(!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("coursel")) so you don't end up injecting the script multiple times into the page